# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') Lottie React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lottie, sanity

I get an undefined issue while trying to set lotties using [lottie-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lottie-react)
I am setting CDN link instead of just importing it directly .
This is the code :

```
{missions.map((mission : any) => 
   (
<div className='bg-[#000000] flex-1'>
<Lottie animationData={mission?.manuscript?.asset.url} loop={true} />
</div>
   )}
```

Eventually I get an issue of Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

```
  577 |               var layerData;
  578 |               var i;
> 579 |               var len = layers.length;
  580 |               var j;
  581 |               var jLen;
  582 |               var k;
```

{mission?.manuscript?.asset.url} is not undefined !
Any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: any updated on this issue?